# Add a text filter field to select in TYPO3

Tags: select, filter, typo3

Hi guys I am struggling with TYPO3 and I would like to do a search filter on my select.
I have this TCA for my select. I added there also this `'enableMultiSelectFilterTextfield' => true,` but nothing changes. Is there a way how to achieve this?

```
$fields = array(
'my_plugin' => array(
    'label' => 'my Fields',
    'exclude' => 1,
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'enableMultiSelectFilterTextfield' => true,
        'maxitems' => 99999,
        'itemsProcFunc' => 'tx_get_list->getList',
        'items' => array(

        ),
    ),
)
```

);

Comment: Your code is not TypoScript. It looks like TCA. Maybe this helps https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select.html#columns-select-properties-multiselectfilteritems

Comment: I had a same question but I am not sure if the manual @HeinzSchilling postet works for signle select field. It looks like, it is for something advanced.

Comment: `enableMultiSelectFilterTextfield` is defined for render type `selectMultipleSideBySide` only - did you try to set [`renderType`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/Reference/Columns/Select/#rendertype) manually? What‘s your TYPO3 version anyway?